# How do I delete certain html on media queries?(on iphone it won't be there)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I know how to edit css on media queries, but how do I make it so that when the screen is less than 500px, certain html tags aren't even there? Thanks

Comment: you could use `display : none;`

Comment: You could remove them via javascript but you'd still be using media queries to detect them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. They will always be part of the DOM (at least until you start adding JavaScript into the mix).

The closest you can come would be to write a style that sets them to `display: none` so they won't be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Below 500px screen size, you can hide the html tags you want.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    p {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will hide the tag, not remove it.  You'd have to use JS in order to remove the element altogether.

Comment: @AndrewIce: Oh ok. He mentioned "certain html tags aren't even there" I thought he wants to hide the elements.

Comment: Ahh, apparently from the comment he listed, that was it.  My apologies.  I thought he had wanted to remove it entirely.